# Are there sources that permit or prohibit co-ed learning of self-defense?

Tags: halacha, tznius-modesty, priorities, pikuachnefesh-danger-life

Learning self-defense in a co-ed environment could be considered prevention of problems that could lead to pikuach nefesh (danger to life). Prohibiting a co-ed environment could be considered placing a protective fence around [tznius](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/592), especially because a self-defense class include a student's breaking a hold or generating force to fend off a large male.

Are there sources, therefore, that permit learning self-defense in a co-ed environment?
-or-
Are there sources that justify prohibiting learning self-defense in a co-ed environment?

Comment: How are you defining p'kuach nefesh ? if the situation hasn't arisen yet, or there is less of a x% chance of being attacked can we still rely on the heter (or mandate) of pikuach nefesh ? at what point does pikuach nefesh start ? is your case one of a safek pikuach  nefesh vs. a Vadai lack of modesty ?

Comment: @eramm yes, I think defining Pekuach Nefesh is an important start, as well as weighing in whether or not participating in co-ed self defense is truly a halachick issue or it is a protective fence.

Comment: Would there be physical contact between the genders, or would they just be in the same room?